# SQL: Select Between Nth Occurrences of Same Character

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a string

`"https://www.facebook.com/9876543219876/posts/123456789123456/"`

and am looking for the following:

`1. Select only 123456789123456 (between 5th and 6th occurrence of '/'`

`2. Select only 9876543219876 (between 3rd and 4th occurrence of '/'`

I tried using combinations of right, charindex and reverse but I could not get the query to return between the multiple occurrence of the characters.

For example I tried

`right("String",charindex('/',reverse("String"))- 1)`

but could only get after the first occurrence from the right.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: What RDBMS?  Please show your current attempts.

Comment: The Oracle INSTR function allows you to chose which occurrence of a string it returns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`regex_substr` is what you need.

```
select regexp_substr(<col>, '[^/]+', 1, 1) as val1, 
       regexp_substr(<col>, '[^/]+', 1, 2) as val2, 
       regexp_substr(<col>, '[^/]+', 1, 3) as val3,
       regexp_substr(<col>, '[^/]+', 1, 4) as val4,
       regexp_substr(<col>, '[^/]+', 1, 5) as val5
from
<your table>
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/E7ILCotW)